# Xamarin Forms - Picker set selected item

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a picker where I update the current address of the user/retailer. The selected value is from my database I want to set the selected item of my picker.

My XAML:

```
<local:CustomPicker x:Name="provincePicker" SelectedIndexChanged="provincePicker_SelectedIndexChanged" Unfocused="provincePicker_Unfocused" SelectedItem="{Binding DisplayText}" ItemsSource="{Binding ProvinceID}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding DisplayText}" StyleClass="fieldForm" IsEnabled="True">
<local:CustomPicker.FontFamily>
     <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
         <On Platform="Android" Value="HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt.otf#HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt"/>
     </OnPlatform>
</local:CustomPicker.FontFamily>
```

XAML.CS

```
var getCode = conn.QueryAsync<RetailerGroupTable>("SELECT * FROM tblRetailerGroup WHERE RetailerCode=?", code);
var resultCount = getCode.Result.Count;

if (resultCount > 0)
{
   var result = getCode.Result[0];
   provincePicker.SelectedItem = result.ProvinceID;
}
```

Comment: to start with, ItemsSource="{Binding ProvinceID}", it doesn't appear that you are setting your ItemsSource correctly.  It should be set to some IEnumerable, not a single value.  Then SelectedItem should be set to an element from the ItemsSource Collection

Comment: @Jason can you show me how to fix this?

Comment: @Jason I can list the provinces but I cant select value from my database

Comment: are you also assigning ItemsSource in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the key properties involved in configuring a `Picker`

- `ItemsSource` this should be an `IEnumerable<T>`, ie a `List<MyClass>` or `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`
- `SelectedItem` - this should be set to an object that is contained in the `ItemsSource` collection
- `ItemDisplayBinding` - this is the name of a Property of `MyClass` that will be displayed to the user in the `Picker`